# Installing OpenCV_contrib modules for Python on Windows

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, pip, opencv3.0

I've downloaded **opencv 3.1** and the **opencv_contrib** files. I require the face module. I've also installed **cmake** and have attempted installation through that.

I've attempted to follow the readme here: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/README.md

But I'm unsure how to build and install it. Which generator am I meant to select for the project in cmake for it to function with Python? Currently I've chosen VS2015. How would I progress from having generated the .sln file?

Thanks